# How can I force linux to limit the amount of time I play "games" on it per day, that would be protected from root override?

Tags: linux, users, root, daemon, process-management

### Problem:

1. Struggling with video game addiction.
2. https://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/v0wj7i/is_there_a_way_to_limit_gaming_time/ 
    Virtually no existing ways to limit gaming, outside therapy.
3. I need `root` for work.

   - `root` gives the power to override any invented limit.

### Tools:

1. I am a fairly talented Qt programmer, but I am only moderately familiar with the Linux Architecture. I am willing to touch kernel code if need be.
2. I have **a lot** of time to throw at this.

### Thoughts:

1. If I own a machine:

   - I can do anything with it.
   - There is no hurdle I can not overcome.
2. Reinstalling a Machine however is a hurdle.

   - Requires a lot of reorganizing & setup.
   - That will have to suffice to dissuade myself from relapsing and reinstalling OS to play games.
3. A holistic ban on gaming will encourage one to attempt a reinstall.

   - It is probably best therefore to go with daily alloted time limits.
4. If I could perhaps create a privelege untouchable from root, that I could have a friend set up a password upon my behalf, who's narrow task would simply be to prevent gaming processes from running too long.

### Goals:

1. Create a privelege that is untouchable by root, who's ownership can be delegated to a trusted friend wherein the only means to disable this privelege is through that friend.
2. Task that privelege to managing gaming processes 
   [ The details for that are unimportant for now. The initial goal would simply be to limit steam's runtime per day, which should be somewhat rudimentary. ]

### Question:

Pertaining to Goal 1,

1. Can I create a privelege or user that is untouchable by root? Does this even question make sense given the architecture?
2. Could this be tasked with a program that exercised overlordship over any designated "gaming process", that would load neccessarily upon login?

Thanks.

Comment: Di your work on another maxhine where you don't have games, and let a friend have the root account to your gaming machine. Or similarly work on a VM where you have root permissions (bur where games don't work). In any case, no technology can actually stop you from reinstalling, or just buying a gaming console or so.

Comment: That solution will not work for me. `no technology can actually stop you from reinstalling` I covered that in my question.

Comment: As you say, no technology can stop you from doing whatever you want on a machine you have physical possession of (even if you didn't already have root access, it's not hard to get root on a machine in your possession).   The only real solution is to keep practising your self-discipline.  If you only ever rely on a crutch to avoid developing self-discipline, then you will never be able to do it without that crutch.  Some problems just don't have a good technological solution.

Comment: You could set up a cron job that runs once/minute during the "no gaming" hours to detect whether steam is running or if any games are being played and either kill steam & the game (likely to cause you to just disable the cron job) or pop up a message reminding you that you don't want to play games at this time (you could still disable the cron job, but maybe you'd be less likely to do so)